# parsing ' inside $( )

Tags: bash, parsing, echo, gdal

I have a bit complicate question i hope i will be able to express in a clear way.

I have a bash script that is create arguments for a command line options.

my script

```
./align_v1.1  reference.tif -te -tr -t_srs
```

produce (by an internal echo) the following string

```
-te -7575475.504 -2950763.205 -6304972.004 -2027871.240 -tr 1110.579983028509332 -1110.579983028509332 -t_srs '+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '
```

this string can be used as command line options

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -te -7575475.504 -2950763.205 -6304972.004 -2027871.240 -tr 1110.579983028509332 -1110.579983028509332 -t_srs '+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ' input.tif output.tif
```

so i should be able to pass the same string in the following way

```
gdalwarp -overwrite $(./align_v1.1 reference.tif -te -tr -t_srs) input.tif output.tif
```

but i get the following ERROR

```
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
'+proj=sinu
```

seems to me that the gdalwarp does not see the leading `'` as a quote when it comes from  `$()`, but it prints fine with just echo.

Is any solution to force `$()` to produce a string that will not get
stop after `'+proj=sinu`

or

Is there any solution to force `$()` to produce and entire string that can be passed to gdalwarp?

I have already tried printf rather than echo

```
#!/bin/bash -c ' ...... ' _
```

but i think is the `$()`

Comment: There is no good solution for this.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) You aren't using a variable, but many of the same principles apply.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that bash has to parse the command-line, and decide where to break the command-line into different words, which it then feeds to $0 (in your case, $0 is "gdalwarp").

The problem is that some of your command-line arguments are being provided by another program, being invoked inside of the $( ) construct.

Bash is trying to parse the output of $( ), and making a mistake in how it interprets the single quotes.

You can fix the entire thing by putting "eval" in front of "gdalwarp", like this:

```
eval gdalwarp -overwrite $(./align_v1.1 reference.tif -te -tr -t_srs) input.tif output.tif
```